# What does the symbol $\prec$ mean in $n^a\prec n^b$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

[image: equation symbol]

I'm taking a course on Coursera called Algorithm Toolbox and found $\prec$ in this equation and don't know what it means.

Comment: Do you mean the symbol after $n^a$ ($n^a$ is just exponentiation) ?

Comment: $n$ is raised to $a$. that is $n$ is multiplied $a$ times.

Comment: sorry, I didn't explain well, I mean the symbol after n^a , that looks like this (<).

Comment: The book must define this on some previous page. I think it is pronounced "precedes" but I don't know what you book means when it says one function $n^a$ precedes another $n^b$.

Comment: It's probably a function growth order symbol, specifically the version (there are several ways of measuring how rapidly a function approaches $\infty$ or approaches $0)$ in which "$f$ curvy-less-symbol $g$" means $\lim \frac{f}{g} = 0.$ The nature of the limit (variable approaching $\infty$ or $0,$ or even possibly something else) will depend on the growth context, which you have not provided in your question.

Comment: Perhaps $\;\prec\;$ is the symbol of Hardy, which is the  equivalent to the $\;O\;$ of Landau: $n^a\prec n^b \iff \exists k>0$ such that $n^a\leq k\cdot n^b$ definitively on $n$, i.e. for $n\geq$ of a certain $\nu$.  
But only perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, in the given context the symbol $\prec$ seems to be an equivalence of the little-$o$ notation.

We can consider the definition of little-$o$ notation:

Let $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ be function defined as $f,g: \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} $. We have $f(n) = o(g(n))$ if for any real $c > 0$, exists an integer constant $n_0 > 0$ such that $ 0 \leq f(n)<c g(n), \forall n \geq n_0$.

Note that there is no negative run time for an algorithm, that's why we have a positive integer.

As $f(n) = o(g(n))$ states $f$ growns much slower than $g$, as $n \to \infty$ the growth of $g$ is just much larger. We say $\lim _{n\to \infty}\dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 0$.

Hardy and Wright $1979$ (*An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers*) defined $f\prec g$ to mean the same as $f= o(g)$, thus

$$f\prec g\iff \exists n_0>0\colon \forall n > n_0 \colon f(n)<g(n)$$

As is written $n^a\prec n^b$ for $0<a<b$
$$n^a\prec n^b \iff \exists n_0>0:n^a\leq n_0\cdot n^b$$